# How can I pause the game when my app goes into the background?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I got a Tetris game and when the game is being played and after the application goes into the background, it continues working so that the player loses the game after a period of time. I want to make my game paused when the application is phased down.

How can I respond to changes in the state of the application (background or foreground)?

Comment: When you say 'phased down', do you mean put into the background?

Comment: yea, well, when "home" button on device is pushed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your app delegate implement `-applicationWillResignActive:` and pause the game.